# OnCollisionEnter not working when I increase the speed

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

In unity I created 6 box collider and shaped like a cube. Inside cube has a sphere.[image: screen of sceen]This my sphere movement script.

```
private Vector3 moveDirection=new Vector3();
  

      public float speed = 7;
        private void Start()
        {
            moveDirection = transform.forward;
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            var transform1 = transform;
            transform1.position += moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        }
    
        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            moveDirection = Vector3.Reflect(moveDirection, collision.contacts[0].normal);
        }
```

As you can  see if you run this sphere will move infinitely inside the cube but if try to change speed to 60 or higher speed sphere goes outside of the cube. So how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to help with collision, the reason the collisions are not "working" is because your Sphere is moving so fast that it never touches the collider, it skips it entirely.

There are a few things you can do to try fix it.

If you have a rigidbody attached to your sphere, you can set the RigidBody Interpolate to 'Interpolate'
[Read up here on what that does](https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/08/unity-rigidbodys-interpolate-property/)

You can also set the Collision Detection to Continuous Dynamic.

Attach the **DontGoThroughThingsScripts** to your sphere                    [Read up here on the DontGoThroughThingsScripts](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DontGoThroughThings). It works by raycasting between your last point and your current point, and if it hits a collider it moves you back to where you should've collided

In [Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html)
Set the Default Solver Iterations to a higher value. This increases the accuracy by
running it more times and removing error.

Lastly, you can also increase the size of your colliders, making it harder for the sphere to miss(Not a permanent or clean way to fix)

Be warned, this will have a large impact on performance. It is a trade off that is unavoidable.